# HTML select tag default option showing blank on IE10

Tags: html, angularjs, select, browser, internet-explorer-10

I am working on an angularjs project where I am using HTML select tag to show a dropdown but I am facing a specific issue in IE10 where the default option is not visible for first time when i select any option the first letter is visible then again if i select any option the full value can be seen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing some of your code would be helpful.

Here is an example of a possible solution. Assume we have the following data:

```
$scope.items = [
    { Name: 'First', Id: 1 },
    { Name: 'Second', Id: 2 },
    { Name: 'Third', Id: 3 },
];
```

You can show it in the template for example in this way:

```
<select ng-model="selected"ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in items">
    <option value="">-- select --</option>
</select>
```

Check the documentation for [more info](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Comment: the issue is coming only if the select tag is inside any ng-if condition